# Background gradient not showing [Bootstrap 3]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap 3 framework for developing a website. I have created a color gradient and inserted it into my main body in the css files correctly, the html files is also correctly linked to the css file and there is no pathing issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: How should we able to help you? You have not provided an example or even a link to a demonstration site. Provide more information and ask a clear question. "Any suggestions" isn't one.

Comment: A clear explanation of the problem in hand? Also what you would like to achieve? Code example on here or jsfiddle would be great so we can check the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need to use **!important**,
for example:

```
#div{
background: white !important;
}
```